Introduction of a connector to replace a relative satz when converting from passive to active

Wandeln sie aktiven Sätze ins Passiv um and umgekehrt, wenn möglich
Q: Manche Kunstoffobjekte werden von Organismen bewachsen, die ihr spezifisches Gewicht erhöhen.
Ans: Organismen bewachsen manche Kunstoffobjekte, wodurch ihr spezifisches Gewicht erhöht wird.

I identify that we can convert a passive sentence to an active sentence here. However, it is not clear to me why we introduced the connector here to replace the relativ sentence. Could somone explain?

This exercise is not very well thought out, imo: Why use a complex sentence to go back and forth with passivisation in both directions simultaneously? And then using a relative clause with a subject pronoun, but the subject is what has to disappear in the passivisation. So what to do with the relative clause? The answer is just a stopgap solution that reacts to a self-created problem. There is no real grammar question that comes up here, it's just a clumsy exercise.

Let me present you a simpler example:

Manche Kunstoffobjekte werden von Organismen bewachsen, wodurch sich ihr spezifisches Gewicht erhöht.
Organismen bewachsen manche Kunststoffobjekte, wodurch sich ihr spezifisches Gewicht erhöht.

Or, if you want passive voice in the adverbial clause:

Manche Kunstoffobjekte werden von Organismen bewachsen, wodurch ihr spezifisches Gewicht erhöht wird.
Organismen bewachsen manche Kunststoffobjekte, wodurch ihr spezifisches Gewicht erhöht wird.

Your example question does not feature such an adverbial clause but a relative clause instead. The problem with that is that this particular relative clause explains the subject of the main clause. And the subject changes when you turn the main clause from passive to active voice. That would lead to

Organismen bewachsen manche Kunstoffobjekte, die ihr spezifisches Gewicht erhöhen.

which has still that tight affinitity to the subject. But the subject changed! So it now means a different thing. That's why the author of that question switched to the adverbial clause which does not cling to the subject that tightly.
Unfortunately it's super tricky to know whether a relative or adverbial clause clings to the subject or the thing mentioned right before. This depends on context. I personally regard all those sentences as highly ambiguous.
